# MakeFile error too many arguments

Tags: makefile

I am doing a simple make file and iam getting the error too many arguments. I do not know what it is talking about

here is my code

```
project1: *.cpp *.h
    g++ -o main *.cpp
```

here is what the terminal is saying

```
unixapps1:project1> project1: *.cpp *.h
project1:: Too many arguments.
```

Comment: How are you invoking the makefile? Do you just type `make`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems are two-fold:

1. You have an awfully large number of source files in your directory — so much so that the length of the names is too long for your shell.
2. You are mis-executing the `makefile` as if it was a shell script.  The error message is what you'd get if you ran `sh makefile` and the `project1:` line was the first (non-blank, non-comment) line in it.

You need to run `make` or (if the makefile is named `project1.mk`) `make -f project1.mk`.

If I've guessed wrong (I hope I have), then you need to clarify what is prompt and what is command line in your question.  Conventionally, you use `$` as the shell prompt (for `sh` and relatives; `%` if you're using C shell or one of its relatives, or `#` if you're running as root — which you should not be doing if you are programming).